# Mover um arquivo adicionado no input file para uma pasta e pegar o caminho(url)

Tags: php

Tenho um input type file onde gostaria de mover o arquivo para uma pasta e pegar o caminho desse arquivo para guardar no banco, utilizando php, se possível queria criar uma hierarquia de mês e ano na hora de criar as pastas de upload(mas é opcional).

Eu tentei isso, mais esta dando erro:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], '/uploads/'.basename($_FILES['arquivo']['name']));
$link = __DIR__ .'/uploads/'.$_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

print_r($link);
```

Comment: Em `$_FILES['name_do_seu_input']` tem todos os dados do arquivo, inclusive a localização dele no disco. Com isso você pode movê-lo para qualquer lugar com (`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Comment: Alterei a pergunta com o código que tentei, mais esta dando erro:

 Notice: Undefined index: arquivo in C:\wamp64\www\projeto\intermediadoras\intermediadorPortaria.php on line 7

Comment: Como está o formulário que você está usando para enviar o arquivo? E se der um `print_r($_FILES)`, vem o que?

Comment: vlw, mais já consegui resolver, coloquei a resposta na pergunta.

Comment: Victor, coloque a resposta na resposta :) Quero dizer, aqui a gente usa a área da pergunta só pra pergunta mesmo, e a área abaixo para as respostas. Pode postar a sua resposta lá embaixo, e até marcá-la como aceita se quiser. Não tem problema responder à própria pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu consegui entender bem o que você quer, basta verificar se o `dir` existe, feito isso você cria ou não cria um diretorio, e terá no final o caminho completo.

```
$diretorio = date('m-Y') . '/';
$arquivo   = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

if(!is_dir($diretorio)){
   mkdir($diretorio, 0700)
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $diretorio . basename($arquivo));

$link = __DIR__ .$diretorio.$arquivo

print_r($link);
```

Comment: não usei exatamente seu código, mais ele ajudou muito, vou editar e colocar o resultado.